# Removing extension by htaccess causes links to break

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I added an htaccess rule to allow `courses/` instead of `courses.php` in URL, but it seems to break all the links in the page with a generic "not found" error. This is because it starts searching for the directory "courses/".

Here's my htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^course/([^/]+)/?$ course.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php [L]
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: No for heavens sake dont use absolute paths. The site will never be movable.

Comment: You need to fix your rewrite rules so they dont play with the things you want left alone

Comment: Feel free to suggest a fix of rewrite rule. Don't want to get into arguments but if OP wants to use any pretty URLs schemes using absolute URLs is the cleanest solution. There are several ways to keep site movable/portable like keeping base path in a variable or utility function like Wordpress or other CMS frameworks.